# I'm inventing a new calendar. What are good criteria for the choices of first day, first year, and first hour?

Tags: culture, orbital-mechanics, time, sunlight, time-keeping

I'm inventing a new calendar:

- It will be used worldwide.
- It uses an intercalary (366th) day to be inserted every 4 years.
- If extremely successful (unlikely I know), it will replace the Gregorian calendar not earlier than in a century.
- Its associated set of units of measurement (length, mass, etc.) is based on [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units).

What are good criteria for the choice of the first day?

Some possibilities:

- January 3 periapsis
- July 3 apoapsis
- March 20 equinox
- June 21 solstice
- September 22 equinox
- December 21 solstice
- 1 October, the beginning of the dry season (meteorological Tropical season)
- 1 April, the beginning of the wet season (meteorological Tropical season)

What are good criteria for the choice of the first year?

Ideally I would have wanted to pick the year of the Big Bang but even in a century it will never be known with precision.

What are good criteria for the choice of the first hour of the day? The possibilities: the days can start at midnight, sunrise, noon or sunset.

Comment: This seems too broad, you’re asking several different questions here instead of one specific question. This also seems opinion based, how are you going to judge the best answer? Any answer seems like it would be equally valid.

Comment: Now, because why not? Even modern calendars have 3 new years, calendar, tax, school. Everything else is entirely arbitrary.

Comment: I agree with @LiamMorris. While I think this kind of question encourages creativity, it will likely be voted by some as opinion-based. You might want to add some criteria for elegibility of the best answer(s), and possibly make it separate questions

Comment: How would this be different than using Julian days for calculations (besides an earlier epoch) or else why not use Julian and just change the epoch?

Comment: Also, why should there be a year zero at all? There is no zero year in our calendar now and we get along just fine. Similarly, no zero month, no zero day.

Comment: What is the benefit of this Calendar over the Gregorian Calendar?  The Leap day was introduced by that to correct for it's absence in the Julian Calendar.  During the switch in 1582, 10 days were cut October.  The people who went to sleep on October 4 of that year would wake up on October 15.  This change brought the calendar in line with the Equinox as well as corrected the date range for the Easter Celebration (Easter is the first Sunday after the First Full Moon after the Spring Equinox).

Comment: Additionally, as @puppetsock alludes to, there was no change to the calendar between BC/BCE and AD.   But rather a demarkation in time before the birth of Jesus Christ vs. after the birth. (Although a more historical date of the Birth would put it at 3 or 4 AD, rather than 1 AD.

Comment: Why would you pick up year zero? Why would you need to introduce such calendar? How your "zero day" choice is related to the need of new calendar? For example, the periapsis is a movinh holiday with Gregorian calendar. It might be 3rd, but might be 5th, or second of January. How need of new calendar would imply the need to choose that particular day during that particular year in old calendar?

Comment: I think I've got an answer if the question was something like: What are good criteria for choices of first day/year in a calendar? Or, how can I make my new calendar realistically succesful?

Comment: OK. I edited my question. I believe it isn't opinion-based anymore.

Comment: As for why I chose the origin to be year 0 instead of year 1, I think it's best thay way because that's how astronomers use the calendar, they put a year 0, and that way each year corresponds to an integer without skipping the integer 0, I think it makes the calculations easier. But this is off-topic and I don't care about that, so I just removed any mention of year zero in my question.

Comment: I saw your edition. Still, I'm not sure you'll get this question easily reopened. You might want to ask a new one, or -preferably, if you want to play by the rules- go through the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions).

Comment: @BuildingBetterWorlds the problem with your question is that it's not possible to give a 'best' answer to it, even if you change the wording again. The natural units deal with such microscopic fractions of time that even Planck yotta-second is laughably short (5.391×10^−20 seconds). Next, nothing in the day-year cycles divides cleanly at each other. If a fully 'rational' calendar was possible, it would've been already implemented. Instead, the time of the solstice creeps slowly out of sync with day lenght, aphelion moves against the solstice and so on and so forth.

Comment: @BuildingBetterWorlds for the year one, you might want the Holocene era 10,000 BC. Or the Julian era from 4713 BC.  Or chose an era associated with the Roman Empire like the most common traditional date for the founding of Rome 753 BC.  Or the first or second constitutional settlement of Augustus in 27 or 23 BC.  Or the "Byzantine" era of the world from 5509 BC.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question's wording can salvage it.  I'd suggest narrowing your question down to one criteria like what would be the best year to start a calendar on, and add some criteria for what society this calendar is intended for. Programers, Physicists, and Farmers will tend to have very different perspectives on what makes a system of time useful and logical

Comment: Can you indicate why this new calendar is needed, or why it is better than what we have now?  The only possible obvious improvement I can see is moving the leap-day back to the end of the year, where it used to be (that way the nth day of the year is always the same date).